# Keyboard problem on Fujitsu Lifebook E559

Tags: keyboard

I got UBUNTU 23.10. on my new Fujitsu Lifebook E559 in parallel to Win11. The Lifebook keyboard runs with Win11 properly, but not with Ubuntu 23.10 on my notebook. Viewing some user forums I got the impression this is a problem for some users particularly with Fujitsu Lifebooks. To solve the problem for now I will start go back to version 22.04. Hoping that this will solve my problem for now.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the question you have - it is missing. askubuntu.com is about asking for help on particular problems with Ubuntu - not about sharing user experience with no questions.